# How to do a wildcard or regex match on _id in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

From below sample elasticsearch data I want to apply [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html) say `*.000ANT.*` on `_id` so as to fetch all docs whose `_id` contains `000ANT`. Please help.

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "data_collector",
    "_type": "agents",
    "_id": "Org000LAN_example1.com",
    "_score": 1,
    "fields": {
      "host": [
        "example1.com"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "data_collector",
    "_type": "agents",
    "_id": "000BAN_example2.com",
    "_score": 1,
    "fields": {
      "host": [
        "example2.com"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "data_collector",
    "_type": "agents",
    "_id": "000ANT_example3.com",
    "_score": 1,
    "fields": {
      "host": [
        "example3.com"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by wildcard? A wildcard is usually a non-known character or string E,G.: do*g - Returns docs with: Dog, Doug, Doorlug. Searching for the string "000ANT" is just a basic match, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling:Yes, I mean [Elasticsearch regex or wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html) as `000ANT` can be prefixed and postfixed with other string

Comment: Ah! You want partial matching. I will post a more detailed answer.

Comment: Other people beat me to it! I would suggest taking a look at your mapping, you might be able to change it (and then reindex) to better suit your needs! Best of luck =)

Comment: @DanielHoffmann-Mitscherling: Thanks for your solution. Also I cannot change my mapping now :)

Answer (score 12):

This is just an extension on Andrei Stefan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30844443/3074768)

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc['_id'][0].indexOf('000ANT') > -1"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note**: I do not know the performance impact of such a query, most probably this is a bad idea. Use with caution and avoid if possible.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) like this, though it's worth noting that it is not advised to start a wildcard term with `*` as performance will suffer.

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "_uid": "*000ANT*"
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that if the wildcard term you're searching for matches the type name of your documents, using `uid` will not work, as uid is simply the contraction of the type and the id: `type#id`

Comment: What is the type you are referring to? `"_type": "agents",` type is always `agents` in my case..

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. As noted in my answer and Andrei's, if the ID you're looking for includes the term "agents" for whatever reason, then using the `_uid` field in the query won't work because that will match all documents.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
{
   "filter": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "regexp": {
                  "_uid": {
                     "value": ".*000ANT.*"
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Since my regex can never have `agents` which is `_type` for my document and your's is the 1st answer. I am accepting your solution. Thanks :) Check comments [here for more details](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30844555/707414)

Answer (score 5):

Allow your mapping for the id to be indexed:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "agents": {
        "_id": {
        "index": "not_analyzed"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use a `query_string` to search for it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "_id:(*000ANT*)",
      "lowercase_expanded_terms": false
    }
  }
}
```

Or like this (with scripts and still querying only the `_id`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.Uid.splitUidIntoTypeAndId(new org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef(doc['_uid'].value))[1].utf8ToString().contains('000ANT')"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change my mapping now.

Comment: Using `_uid` will get you wrong results in case you are searching for things that match the `type` name. For example, searching for `"_uid": {
              "value": ".*agents.*"
            }` will return everything.

Comment: Can we achieve it using script? Something like `"script": "(doc['_uid'].value=='.*0001MT_CAW18141225100.*' )"`

Comment: Updated my answer. Even if you see `_uid` in there, `.splitUidIntoTypeAndId(new org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef(doc['_uid'].value))[1]` will consider the `_id`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here, the first is to use partial matching, which is easiest by wrapping a query with wildcards similar to other answers. This works on not_analyzed fields and is case sensitive.

```
POST /my_index/my_type/_search
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "_id": {
          "value": "*000ANT*"
       }
    }
}
}
```

The second option is to use ElasticSearch analyzers and proper mapping to describe the functionality you are looking for, you can read about those [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/analysis-analyzers.html).

The basic premise is that you introduce an analyzer in your mapping which has a tokenizer, which will break strings down into smaller tokens that then can be matched. Doing a simple query search for "000ANT" on the tokenized _id field will return all result with that string.