# Elastic search: Delete types that start with the same prefix

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I am using the elasticsearch library for node. I would like to know if, the same way you can delete specific indices that start with a certain prefix with the help of a wildcard (e.g:'prefix-*'), is there also a similar way to delete certain types of an index that start with the same prefix?

Comment: How about reading the [api description](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-delete)?

Comment: I've read it and couldn't find a solution that uses wildcards for type or id. the only one that may work is the deleteByQuery but even then it says nothing about wildcards, hence the question i've made: to know if anyone knows if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: [`indices.deleteAlias()`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-deletealias): "... index: A comma-separated list of index names (**supports wildcards**); use _all for all indices ..."; [`indices.deleteMapping`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-deletemapping): "... type: A comma-separated list of document types to delete (**supports wildcards**); use _all to delete all document types in the specified indices. ..."

Comment: thank you. the problem is i also have the same problem for _id and i couldn't find anything with wildcards for _id. is there an alternative?

Comment: let me google this for you... 20 seconds later: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844122/how-to-do-a-wildcard-or-regex-match-on-id-in-elasticsearch

Comment: thank you... i've tried google it before but i couldn't find that answer...maybe i was not using the right words or something. anyway thankyou very much for the help.