# Elastic search simple query to find all ids

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get all id's for a type, but I am pulling my hair out.

Please see my attacment.

HERE IS THE cURL call :

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-d'{ "query": { "wildcard" : { "id" : "Account[enter image description here][1]*" }    }}'
```

[cURL call with no results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjSaZ.png)

Comment: It is possible that your `id` field is a `text` field (or analyzed string) and thus you need to search for `a*` instead of `A*`

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am a complete noobie to ES. Our ID is really what I want to search on. We store them like this: /licenses/context/{license}-{context}. Here is a real one: /licenses/context/f3a541c5aafb447af264fd7cb0be23bb-18f03af2-e164-f722-52fa-58b3671de012. I can seem to search on the ID.

Comment: Try with query `{ "query": { "wildcard" : { "id" : "account*" }    }}` instead

Comment: it worked, thank you, I forgot to mention that I am trying fir the UID field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess there is an issue with the way your id-field is analyzed. You can retrieve the mapping by using the _mapping endpoint (described in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html)). Your id field should be analyzed as a string (with break characters, tokenizers and all) for the wildcard query to work. If it is not analyzed, as you might expect for an id-field, the wildcard query will not work. Then you would need to change the mapping and reindex your data to make it work.

Comment: Val, I am trying to actually perform the search on _uid. Can the _uid be analyzed. I suppose that I could also put the _uid in the fields. Let me know if I can post my mappings.

Comment: Hmmm, I see I might be wrong about the wildcard query not working. Have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844122/how-to-do-a-wildcard-or-regex-match-on-id-in-elasticsearch